# How to get data from stored sql procedure in dataset with SqlDataAdapter?

Tags: c#, sql, dataset

Is this good approach to get data from stored procedure? For example procedure is making `select * from base`. Here is my code but I need help with dataset and adapter:

```
public static DataSet Osvezi(string naziv_tablice)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = null;
    DataSet dataset = null;
    SqlConnection konekcija = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["skripta"]);

    if (konekcija != null)
    {

        try
        {
            if (konekcija.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                konekcija.Open();

            cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = konekcija;

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "Osvezi";

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tablica", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = naziv_tablice;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            // Fill the DataSet using default values for DataTable names, etc
            da.Fill(dataset);

            return dataset;
        }

        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            //Obravnava napak

        }

        finally
        {
            konekcija.Close();
            konekcija.Dispose();
            cmd.Dispose();

        }

        return dataset;

    }
    return dataset;

}
```

Comment: code looks good, whats the problem you are facing in this?

Comment: why there  is "cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); "?

Comment: Does your stored procedure contains a non optional parameter named "@dataSet"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this one instead:

```
public static DataSet Osvezi(string naziv_tablice)
{

        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection konekcija = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["skripta"]))
            {

                konekcija.Open();

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = konekcija;

                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.CommandText = "Osvezi";

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tablica", naziv_tablice??DBNull.Value);

                    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        // Fill the DataSet using default values for DataTable names, etc
                        DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
                        da.Fill(dataset);

                        return dataset;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            //Obravnava napak

        }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Corrected tre param type following the SP script

Comment: It's working I used this code to retrieve data if somone needs maybe : ` foreach (DataRow dr in dataset.Tables[0].Rows)

                            {

                                string myVar = dr["ime_uporabnika"].ToString();
 

                            } ` thank you!!

Comment: You forgot to close the connection, which is extremely important.

Comment: Well it's not in the code sample you posted? Or are you relying on the "using" statement doing it when it garbage collects?

Comment: @NickG On normal workflow (including unhandled exceptions) "using" forces connection to close or move to connections pool. On abnormal flow, causing the termination of the process - the connections are closed too. "using" has no any connection to the garbage collection, it is a "disposable" pattern, nothing more

Answer (score 2):

Please correct the following.

You don't need to open the connection.
 
There shouldn't be any command.ExecuteNonQuery.
The parameter in the method is string but the datatype of SqlParameter is SqlDbType.Int.